# What is the "derive" key usage?

Tags: tls, web-browser

Google Chrome gives a lot of SSL information. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Under "Key Usage", what does "Derive" mean?

Comment: Are you able to provide the OID of the key usages (e.g. 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)

Comment: Purpose 1 is 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 and purpose 2 is 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a Chrome popup; it is a *MacOS X* popup. Chrome delegates certificate management to the underlying OS. You get this popup only with Chrome on MacOS X (on Linux you will have the Gnome certificate viewer, on Windows the Windows certificate viewer).

The OS X certificate viewer shows the "Key Usages" which are defined in the "Key Usage extension" as specified in [RFC 5280, section 4.2.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3). This (optional) extension describe the usages for which the public key contained in the certificate may be used. OS X translates the combination of flags into a combination of "usage words" and there is not a 1-to-1 mapping. You get "Derive" when the `keyAgreement` key usage is specified (which is normal for a SSL server certificate with a RSA key); to get "Encrypt", you need either the `dataEncipherment` flag, or the combination of `keyAgreement` and `keyEncipherment`. `keyEncipherment` triggers "Wrap". You also get "Encrypt, Verify, Derive" if the key has type RSA and there is no Key Usage extension at all.